Birth Date insists on time in FormBuilder
I have Birth Date on a form created in FormBuilder and the default date picker includes time as well as date. I can't hide the time, and the form fails to submit if time is empty (the field isn't required so it only fails if there's a date with no time).
On WordPress and CiviCRM 5.78.0
Can I remove this? Is it a bug?

That sounds like a regression. I will debug...

@Coleman did you make any progress on this?

@Coleman , if it helps, I did incremental updates on my test installation of Civi and this issue appeared after I went from 5.77.1 to 5.78.0. Before that, the update from 5.76.2 to 5.77.1 was clean meaning I didn't receive any errors however when I updated to 5.78.0, I received the "afform_scanner". I'm not sure if the update to 5.78.0 broke it or if the afform_scanner error did.

Thanks. Can you please review this fix: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/31338

Looks good and it passed some quick tests in my playground. Thanks for jumping on this so quickly.

You're welcome. Thanks for jumping in to review.

@Coleman much appreciated, it's also working on my WP site :)

This was a bug. I have created this Pull-Request to fix it: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/31338
